# how to log insert/update query's for a specific table in mysql 5

Tags: logging, mysql5

does anyone knows if it is possible to log all insert/update query's for a specific table in mysql 5?

We got multiple applications querying the same database, so implementation of this in the data access layer (two many apps) is quite unrealistic, would be much easy if we can just turn a switch on in the configuration file in the database.  I realize we could log all query's but that would be quite a performance hit.

Comment: Wouldn't you want to know which application is doing the insert/update?  If you rely on database level logging, you won't be able to fully control what goes in the log.

Comment: Neatly designed DB system shouldn't care very much about which application does what. Maybe only when something starts to behave really bad, but there are other methods to solve those situations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This thing is called "audit trail". Google should give you a fair amount of answers.